# Unit Testing Generic Methods (NUnit)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, nunit

I have been trying to implement the repository pattern in .Net Core using a generic class. This is what i have come up with (ive taken out all but one method to keep it simple). The class / method works, but im trying to write a unit(integration) test for it, in this case the Add Method.

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

     public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }
}
```

So far my integration test is as follows,
Set Up makes a SqlLite database to save to
Sets up the DbContext
Sets up a Unit of Work - The unit of work is needed to SaveChanges the the DbContext and can be ignored for the most part

Then im creating a "StorageSystem" Domain Object and testing the Generic class. But it feels like I should be able to test it with out passing a specific domain model. Or at the very least, enter the different domain models as parameterised tests.

```
[TestFixture]
public class RepositoryTests
{
    SqliteConnection _connection;
    DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> _options;
    ApplicationDbContext _context;
    UnitOfWork _uow;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        _connection.Open();

        _options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .UseSqlite(_connection)
            .Options;

        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(_options))
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        _context = new ApplicationDbContext(_options);
        _uow = new UnitOfWork(_context);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_AddsEntityToRepository()
    {
        //arrange
        var storageSystem = new StorageSystem {Id = 1, Name = "Storage1"};
        var repo = new Repository<StorageSystem>(_context);

        //act
        repo.Add(storageSystem);
        _uow.Complete();

        //assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, _context.StorageSystems.Count());
    }
```

I am fairly new to working with Generics, The closest solution I could find was using an abstract class. However I couldnt make it working with me code with it not detecting the tests as an abstract class and not being able to make a repository of type TEntity.

[Example taken from here](http://codinghelmet.com/articles/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-generic-classes)

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class RepositoryTests1<TEntity>
{
    SqliteConnection _connection;
    DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> _options;
    ApplicationDbContext _context;
    UnitOfWork _uow;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        _connection.Open();

        _options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .UseSqlite(_connection)
            .Options;

        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(_options))
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        _context = new ApplicationDbContext(_options);

        _uow = new UnitOfWork(_context);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }

[Test]
public void Add_AddsEntityToRepository_GenericAttempt()
    {
        //arrange
        TEntity entityToAdd = this.CreateEntity();

        var repo = new Repository<TEntity>(_context); //ERROR HERE - TEntity must be a reference type

        //act
        repo.Add(entityToAdd);
        _uow.Complete();

        //assert
        //NO IDEA WHAT THE ASSERTION WOULD BE
    }

    protected abstract TEntity CreateEntity();
}
```

So in short, how do i unit test this Generic Repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Restrict your Repository to a certain base class created by you like EntityBase (this should be abstract)

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    ...
}
```

Then you are able to pass your base type to this test methods.

```
[Test]
public void Add_AddsEntityToRepository()
{
    //arrange
    var storageSystem = new StorageSystem {Id = 1, Name = "Storage1"};
    var repo = new Repository<EntityBase>(_context);

    //act
    repo.Add(storageSystem);
    _uow.Complete();

    //assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1, _context.StorageSystems.Count());
}
```

Since you are ensuring through inherintance, that every type has at least the members of EntityBase, you do not have to test further more down the inheritance tree of your entity types. (unless you have a certain use-case for that)

If you certain methods, that you need to know on the base-type, but the implementation depends on the child class, simply put the method as abstract member in the base class and override it in the child class.

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // sample method that copies member values from other object to current instance
    public abstract void CopyProperties(EntityBase other);
}

public class Student : EntityBase
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public override void CopyProperties(EntityBase other)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using inheritance to verify this, this solution could work. But I have 2 reservations in using this solution.

1. I'm still required to create  a domain model in the test. What if i wanted to test the domain model but didn't have the model available

2. It feels a little wrong that all my domain models should inherit from a EntityBase class just for testing purposes. I can't say what is wrong with this but it feels wrong.

It's definitely better than my solution so far, but i will continue to look for different solutions

Comment: Why does it feel wrong to you, when the BaseClass contains aggregated content from the child classes like an Id. I understand you if you do not want to have an Id at every class.

Comment: What do you think about an Interface like Persistable that all your Entities implement? That would not be as aggressive as an abstract BaseClass.

Comment: You make a valid point actually, if they all have an ID then its the exact purpose an abstract class is design for.

The interface is also a possibility. 

Now i have had time to reflect, i think this is a valid solution.

I will accept this as a solution and implement it (Not sure if by abstract class or interface yet)